# Resharper test runner can't find connection string on Run All

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I have a Visual Studio project structure something like this:

```
Base (no connection string)
Data (connection string to Sql Server, references Base)
Logic (connection string to Sql Server, references Base & Data)
Base.Test (no connection string, references Base)
Logic.Test (connection string to Sql Server, references Base & Data & Base.Test)
```

When I use Resharper to run all the unit tests on each of the test projects separately, they pass.  But when I run all unit tests across all projects, the Base tests pass first and then the Logic tests fail because it can't find the connection string.

When I debug, I can see it does actually have one connection string to SqlExpress, which I gather is being generated by Entity Framework, which seems to come from another project higher up the chain?

How can I get the Logic.Test project to use its own connection string from app.config on Run All?

Comment: How are your Shadow-copy settings and AppDomain settings in Tools -> options | Tools | Unit testing ?

Comment: Shadow-copy ticked.
Use separate AppDomain not ticked.

(i.e. The default Resharper settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believed I had a similar problem a long time ago, and I seem to remember I had to change some ReSharper settings (`ReSharper` -> `Tools` -> `Options` | `Tools` | `Unit testing`)

I'm checking my options right now, and I have Shadow-copy un-ticked and Separate AppDomain ticked.

You should give it a try.

**EDIT**:

it seems just ticking the *Separate AppDomain* checkbox is sufficient, regardless of the *Shadow-copy* setting.

Comment: Ok, just did the opposite: both ticked and the problem goes away.  It's a pity that each developer will have to configure their own machines though.

BUT... I also have the same problem when running NUnit on our TeamCity CI server.  I'm wondering if there are parameters to pass in?

Comment: You can have shared settings in ReSharper with the rest of yuor team, by committing in your CVS a _layer_ of ReSherper settings it's a .dotsettings file. Check this : https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Reference__Settings_Layers.html,

Comment: Ok, tried both unticked and it didn't work.  Only works with both ticked.

Will wait to see if there are any other solutions before I accept the answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry I made a typo, and I fixed my answer with an edit. What I had was the Separate AppDomain ticked.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative solution was to simply duplicate the app.config onto the Base.Test project.  Not ideal as conceptually that project didn't relate to database work at all, but the solution did work in both the dev environments and TeamCity test runner.